# C++ Implementing scripting (Repeatable Actions)

Tags: c++, scripting

I have a desktop app written in C++. It does a variety of different things and interacts with a database. I have made most actions that need to be performed selectable from a list. Actions are performed serially on data sets and need to be saved and played back at a later time on a different result set.

The actions are typically performed from a drop down menus and there are no load/save to disk operations. I dont' necessarily need scripting capability, but if thats the easiest way to go that's fine.

How would you approach this?

Added, This application is NOT written in OOP style

Comment: to put a list of c++ actions (as functions behind) a button or in a list is trivial. what is missing in your description: do your users need to create such list of actions?

Comment: I think you missed the thrust of the question

Answer (score 1):

[Lua](http://www.lua.org)

It's a great, simple scripting language, easily embedded into your apps.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the GoF *Command* design pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

- lua with LuaBind is quite widely used
- Python with boost::python is also widely used but heavier on space

Now I know less know scripting languages that are useful in game programming, so useful in whatever application you need scripting for:

- Falcon : the more versatile and flexible solution I know and use
- ChaiScript : the easier to integrate I know
- AngelScript : didn't try yet
- GameMonkey : didn't try yet
- IO : didn't try yet